# How to get post values from first page to third page ,as post

Tags: php

i have 3 pages

`Page1.php,page2.php,page3.php`

In page1.php, i have some hidden values, for example 'name'

After the submission of page1.php, it will go to page2.

Then after some process in page2.php, it should need to automatically submit to page3.php(where page3.php is in another sever)

Finally,when i print the $_POST  variables in page3.php, i need to get the variable 'name'

Answer (score 3):

You will want to look into [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

If you need them in POST, try this:

```
$display = "";
$saveFields = array('one', 'two'); // whitelist of fields to add to the form hidden
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if (!empty($val) && in_array($key, $saveFields)) 
        $display .= '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$val.'" />';
}

echo $display;
```

Should get you where you want to go. The whitelist just ensure's that random stuff is not injected that does not need to be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
But actually the third page 'page3.php' is lies in another server
Also ,i need to get the parameters, when i print $_POST

Comment: Well then, just add them as hidden fields to your forms. Just know that form data is easily modified, IE someone could potentially just send data to page3.php and not have to go through page1 and page2, so you may want to add a unique token that is shared by both servers in some way. So yea, just add them as a hidden input field.

Comment: i donot clear your idea.Will you please explain that how can i get the post values from page1.php to page3.php ?

Comment: @user310849: What specific parts of his answer are you having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 3):

you could stick it in the [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
```

or you could pass them in hidden vars on page2.php if it has a form...

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
But actually the third page 'page3.php' is lies in another server
Also ,i need to get the parameters, when i print $_POST

Comment: @user310849: That information should have been included in your original question. Either way, the second part of this answer still solves your problem: "you could pass them in hidden vars on page2.php if it has a form." Place a form with hidden values on page2 and then javascript POST to page3.

Comment: yea, i understand.Let me know without using javascript(using only php) can we accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Option is to add hidden input on page2 too.

(2) Option is to set the value from page1's name into session and use it on page3

Comment: Thanks for your reply But actually the third page 'page3.php' is lies in another server Also ,i need to get the parameters, when i print $_POST

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions:

- PHP sessions
- cookies
- passing arguments as GET/POST parameters
- storing data in database

In simple cases passing arguments as GET parameter page2.php?name=... or using hidden form field is the best solution

Comment: Thanks for your reply But actually the third page 'page3.php' is lies in another server Also ,i need to get the parameters, when i print $_POST

Answer (score 0):

This seems straightforward to me, page one has a hidden value called `name`. Page 2 should retrieve the post `$_POST['name']` and print it on page 2 as a hidden field. Once you post it to Page 3 you can retrieve it the same way `$_POST['name']`.

Realistically if the data is exactly the same and is being carried all the way to page 3, why do you even need it? Can you not just declare it on page 3?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the way I read this is that on your first page you have a UI with a form. The form is then submitted for processing to page 2. After processing is done, you want to redirect, if you will, the user to another site (or server, doesn't necessarily have to make a difference).

If I got that right, here is what you should do; instead of using the header(); function (php), print an empty page with a hidden form with all of the details you want to send over and use javascript to emulate the user 'submitting' the form.

> < div style="display: none;">
>   < form action="https://mywebpage.com/myscript.php" method=POST>
>   < input type=hidden name="key_1" value="value_1">
>   < input type=hidden name="key_2" value="value_2">
>   < input type=hidden name="key_3" value="value_3">
>   < input type=submit id="formButton" style="visibility: hidden; ">
>   < script language="javascript">
>   document.getElementById("formButton").click()
>   < /form>
>   < /div>

Comment: you are correct.but let me know if there is anything else, ie  without using the javascript submit, for submiting the page2.php and redirect it to page3.php ?

Comment: PHP itself has no option to both send POST data __and__ have the client follow it (unlike ASP). The javascript is the only way I know of to actually push the user to the other site/ server. You can use curl to fetch the page the user would otherwise be redirected to, and display that on your own, but that might screw up some links. curl, however, is a server-side approach and will grab the page (/ content) from another site.