# sending all $_POST[] value to "nextpage."

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

Suppose i have many values here with form method POST

```
$_POST["value1"]
$_POST["value2"]
$_POST["value3"]
$_POST["value4"]
$_POST["value5"]
$_POST["value6"]
$_POST["value7"]
```

**and i want to send them to nextpage.php**

any function to do that? Besides using

```
<form method="POST" action="nextpage.php">
<input type="hidden" name="value1"  value="value1 />
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "next page php"? Do you want to send a POST from the PHP? use curl. or do you mean when the form on the current page is submited? in that case, just set those $_POST['value'] in input tags like you have, that would be the best way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get post values from first page to third page ,as post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207793/how-to-get-post-values-from-first-page-to-third-page-as-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing post values to next page store the complete $_POST superglobal array variable into **session** and then on next page you can access those values using **$_SESSION** variable

Alternatively you can use **curl** to send HTTP request to next page using POST method
Then those variables will be accessible using $_POST variable on next page

Please refer the code snippet mentioned below as an example for sending HTTP request using post method through curl

```
        $url='http://203.114.240.77/paynetz/epi/fts';
 $data = array('login' => '11','pass' => 'Test@123','ttype'  =>'NBFundTransfer','prodid'=>'NSE','amt'=>50,'txncurr'=>'INR','txnscamt'=>0,'clientcode'=>007,'txnid'=>uniqid(),'date'=>date('d/m/Y H:i:s'),'custacc'=>'123456789');
      $datastring = http_build_query($data);
     //die($url.'?'.$datastring);
      $ch=curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datastring);
     $output = curl_exec($ch);
      //echo $output; die;
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

store all your values in `$_SESSION` and use it in next page, or you can create **URL** using these values and redirect your page to `nextpage.php`

Answer (score 2):

### Passing without session

If there is no security concern and your post data contains something like search parameters . For example `$_POST` has

```
array('query'=>'keyword', 'orderby' => 'name', 'range' => '4-10' )
```

You can generate a query string from that data using [http_build_query](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and create anchor tag for user to click and pass on that data to next page along with url.

```php
$url = 'nextpage.php?' . http_build_query($_POST);
```

it will generate a url like `nextpage.php?query=keyword&orderby=name&range=4-10` that you can use in html anchor tag and in next page you can get it from $_GET.

### Using session

Alternatively you already have the option you storing it in `$_SESSION` and after using destroy the `session` in order to keep your site performance up.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Session` or `cookie` to access to other page

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>First page</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById('send').submit()">

<form id="send" action="next_page.php" style="display: none;">
<?PHP
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$val.'" />';
}
?>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @itachi that's up to the OP