# Not getting cURL response

Tags: php, curl, get

When I use header:

```
$url='http://test.com/pay?login=160&pass=Test@123&ttype=NBFundTransfer&prodid=NSE&amt=50&txncurr=INR&txnscamt=0&clientcode=TkFWSU4%3d&txnid='.$string.'&date='.$date.'&custacc=1234567890&udf1=ajeesh&udf2=test@ttr.com';

header ('Location :'.$url);
```

Im getting this XML:

```
<MMP>
<MERCHANT>
<RESPONSE>
<url>http://test.com/pay</url>
<param name="ttype">NBFundTransfer</param>
<param name="tempTxnId">267040</param>
<param name="token">
r2X%2BE87UUszWqAz1xyWLJBlRhLuq7%2B3NdKTuhOb%2BbVw%3D
</param>
<param name="txnStage">1</param>
</RESPONSE>
</MERCHANT>
</MMP>
```

As a response. The same I wanted to do with `curl`. So I tried:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$auth = curl_exec($curl);
echo $auth
```

Where `$url` is the one above.

But when I `echo $auth`, all Im getting is `1` as response and Im not getting the XML. Why is this happening. Is there anything wrong in what I am doing?

Comment: Add this: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

Comment: When I used this,the 1 is gone.Now a blank page is coming

Comment: Try testing with a simple url such as `http://www.google.com`. And as Rolice mentioned in a comment, put a semicolon (`;`) at the end of your `echo` line. Do you see output when you make those changes?

Comment: I have the semi colon.That was a type error.But still.I cant gt anything..nor error is shown

Comment: When I used google,I GOT GOOGLE WEBISITE LOADED IN MY DOMAIN :D

Comment: @PatrickQ please get me a solution

Comment: I'd say it may be a problem with the target API then (i.e. they're blocking certain request types). Do you have documentation for the API you're trying to use?

Comment: They wanted me to post the values as header and parse the xml and the values parsed from it is again need to be sent to another api.Is it possible to parse it?But with header,how ? :(

Comment: @Downvoter : Whoe ever downvoter , please mention if there is something childish about the question,if the downvoter care to give an explanation?

Comment: @PatrickQ Patriq,I am getting 1 as output.Its the last outputof the xml.Any guess?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13669278/1505169), which appears to contain an example using the same API. It looks like you need to be sending your request as a `POST`. Without seeing the exact specs/docs for the API, that's the best I can do for you.

Comment: Awesome man! That way great!! :)

Comment: @PatrickQ Im gettting 505 http status response btw

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, try this

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); //this line
$auth = curl_exec($curl);
echo $auth;
```

Comment: Thanks , but I tried this.But Im getting a blank response

Comment: Give some explanations along with the answer. What is this option and how it affects the process. This way the man that ask the question will understand the solution. @Piya, I see missing `;` at `echo $auth` - if there is other code after that like it will not work.

Comment: @Rolice use `print_r(curl_error($curl));` to find out why.

Comment: @LozCherone, I am not the man posted the question... I just leave some guides for answering, that is why I don't need to `print_r` :D

Comment: @Rolice eek your right lol sorry. **twice i did it even worse** lol

Comment: I was just going to vote up on your community support :P +1 on the answer for the improvement.